# Is it necessary to run own DNS server?

Tags: dns, domains, dns-servers

I would like to buy a second-level domain name (e.g. `example.com`) and I will
run web server on my own machine (named www, having public IP address).

Is this sufficient for my machine to be accessible by visitors via browser
with `http://www.example.com`?

I expect that every visitor machine accessing `http://www.example.com` will first ask
it's DNS server if it knows the IP address of `www.example.com`.
If it doesn't know. The DNS server will ask the root server on the address of .com
top-level domain. Then it will ask .com top-level domain if it knows the IP address
of `www.example.com` and it should be there because I bought it. So finally it will send the IP address to the visitor's DNS server and then visitor's DNS server will send the IP
address to visitor's machine?

I would like to avoid installing and configuring own DNS server (I have only one laptop). Is my expectation correct that I don't need to install own DNS server?

If yes/no, please describe a little the reasoning behind the scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your domain name registrar should be hosting your DNS records. This is not something you have to do or worry too much about. In fact, you are far better off *not* running a DNS server because of the security implications. When you register your domain name many registrars will host your DNS records free of charge. Some do charge a small fee. If your registrar for some extremely odd reason cannot host your DNS records, there are DNS hosts. So there are plenty of options. I suggest making this a question you ask the registrar prior to registering your domain name.